# New to CSS, need help centering articles in a section

Tags: css

```
#animal-stories {
    width:1000px;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:30px;
    border:10px dotted #FF88FF;
    border-left:none;
    border-right:none;

}

article {
    max-width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin:10px;
    background-position:center;
}


.image {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-size:cover !important;
    background-position:center !important;
    margin:auto;
```

```
 <section id="animal-stories">
        <article> <!--NOTICE! To input images in the same parent folder, the entire address isn't necessary. || SPECIAL NOTICE TO ADDING IMAGES THROUGH DIVS IN HTML. This took an hour to figure out!!-->
            <div class="image" style="background: url(Images/angrydog.jpg)"></div>
                <h3> dogs kidnapping!</h3>
                    <p>dogs are out there doign this!! It's crazy!!!<a href="#">read ...</a></p>
        </article>
        <article>
            <div class="image" style="background:url(Images/angrycat.jpg)"></div>
                <h3> cats kidnapping!</h3>
                    <p>cats are out there doign this!! It's crazy!!!<a href="#">read...</a></p>
        </article>
        <article>
            <div class="image" style="background:url(Images/angrycow.jpg)"></div>
                <h3> cows kidnapping!</h3>
                    <p>cows are out there doign this!! It's crazy!!!<a href="#">read...</a></p>
        </article>
        <article>
            <div class="image" style="background:url(Images/angryzebra.jpg)"></div>
                <h3> zebras kidnapping!</h3>
                    <p>zebras are out there doign this!! It's crazy!!!<a href="#">read...</a></p>
        </article>
                </section>
```

I've tried `background-position:center;` on `<section id="animal-stories">`

I've tried messing with  but that does not seem to be my answer.

I just want the images to be in-line and also scale with the size of the section, filling the width completely. I'm not sure if that's because there are slight width-variations on the images as I did set height and width to 100% for the images. I'm new...

Comment: It's not 100% clear what you want. Do you want the image background to completly fill article?